# How to grant a limited (partial) access to workspace?

Tags: jenkins

I'm an android developer and use jenkins to automatically build my app.

I wrote a python script, it pulls codes from git, builds, then puts the output apk file in path `jenkins_job_workspace_root/output/apk/foo.apk`. Then, a test team will test my app. They will login the jenkins server and refer to the output path to download foo.apk.

We assume this:

- The QA team have a Jenkins account named "qateam".
- Jenkins server's URL is something like "http://x.x.x.x:8080/".
- Jenkins job's name is `bar`.

So here is the process that QA team access the output APK file: They login jenkins server as user "qateam", click jenkins job named "bar" then "workspace", arriving here:

[image: figure: workspace]

Question: How do I config jenkins, so the test team would have access to `jenkins_job_workspace_root/output/apk/`, but couldn't read other directory in the jenkins workspace? That is, in above picture, "qateam" can only see "output/apk", while "MainProject" and "LibraryProject(s)" are invisiable.

Now I use "Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin", but it just turn whole workspace on/off:(

Comment: Please specify this steps: "They will login the jenkins server and refer to the output path to download foo.apk.". How do they do this, what are they accessing. Share, HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Jenkins permissions currently work.  Access to the workspace through the dashboard is either on or off.

You can't currently specify only a certain path within the workspace.